# calling __call__ method on Singleton designed based on metaclass

Tags: python

I have the following Python code:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class SingletonClass(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
      
    def out(self):
        print(i)
        print(j)
  
    def __call__(self,i,j) :
    print("call_SingletonClass")
    self.i=i
    self.j=j


x = SingletonClass(1,2)
y = SingletonClass(1,3)
print(x == y)
```

when i am calling  `x = SingletonClass(1,3)` what exactly happens ? and how the `__call__` function is triggered from the `Singleton` class and the *call*_ method not triggered from the SingletonClass Class ?

Comment: Why did you use `i` and `j` in `out` method ? you can't access them. They are local variables to init

Comment: From what I can tell, you don't understand metaclasses, so I closed your question under one about that. If you meant to ask a more specific question, please [edit] to clarify and LMK. For tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Because `SingletonClass` is an instance of `Singleton`. Like any other object, if you do `my_object()` it will use the `__call__` method of that type.

Comment: and if i defined a call method like this under the SingletonClass   def __call__(self,i,j) :
        print("call_SingletonClass")
        self.i=i
        self.j=j  -->why this not triggered but the Singleton __call__ triggered

Comment: @dave ... The *instances* of `SingletonClass` would be callable. That wouldn't affect the class itself, but instances of that class.

Comment: @dave just forget metaclsses for a second, create a class with a `__call__` method, e.g. `class Foo`, then do `instane_of_foo = Foo()`, then *call the instance*, using `instance_of_foo()`

Comment: @dave If you have a metaclass with `__call__` in it, and you implement `__call__` in your class as well, and you do `your_class()()` both of the `__call__`s would be called. The `__call__` in the metaclass is for the first parenthesis, the  `__call__` the class itself is for the second parenthesis.